# Windows WCF service doesn't start after using VS installer - Error 1053

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a window installer that installs my release build service and installs the service. All that works, but when I go to the services.msc, the service is there and set to automatic, but when I start it manually it won't start and fails for "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request" and the service is left in a state set to Starting.

The funny thing is, if I uninstall the service components and install the same service manually using the "sc create "Service" binpath= "Path to serviceName" start= auto then go into the services.msc and start it manually it all works.

What can't I start the service after the installer installs it since it's the same build of code as when I install and start manually. Does anyone know how to fix this strange problem?

Update:
One thing I have noticed is, the service starts fine w/ the installer if the code is built in debug mode vs. release mode. I don't know why that is because I can install and start the service manually from the release folder in the VS dev solution, but when the release build is installed away from the solution, it fails to start. Maybe it's a rights permission thing and I need to do something different when starting the service w/ the release build. I know you can change the permission on the service before starting it, currently it's set to Local Service, but maybe that is wrong, not sure.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   _cHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebService.Service));
   _cHost.Open();
}
```

Comment: Is the account used to log on the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes it is. It's craziest thing. I can install the service manually as I said from the release build using a batch file w/ the "sc create" via admin mode, but when the installer adds the service from the install code folder which is same as what's in the release folder /w the exception of the .pdb files, I can't start it and it just times out.

Comment: Do you have any branching based on solution config like #if DEBUG?

Comment: Actually no I don't. Do you think when I start the service after it's installed via the installer that I'd need to run service.msc in admin mode to start it? I don't need to do this though when I install and start manually w/o the VS installer.

Comment: "I have a window installer that installs my release build service and installs the service." How did you get the installer? Visual Studio Installer project?

Comment: Yes this a Visual Studio Installer Project. What's weird is, if I install and start the service directly out of my Release folder, it starts just fine. However, if I manually move the Release folder to my Program Files(x86) to simulate what the installer does, then install/start the service manually, it also fails to start. It's almost like it can run outside of my VS code solution folder itself.

Comment: Made an update above w/ new finding.

Comment: So your OnStart() takes too long. Can you tell us what your code does in that method or better provide the code ? It's also convenient to include some EventLog.WriteEntry("Service is initializing FooBar", EventLogEntryType.Information, 1234); lines.

Comment: I posted the OnStart method above which basically doesn't do much =)  What's interesting is, I changed the Visual Studio installer to use the active build versus the specific Release build and now it works, it's really weird since I don't understand why.  But hey, it works now =)